# How to insert a picture in wordDocument.header using late binding from excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, late-binding

from EXCEL VBA I want to insert a picture in a word document
I can open a word document
but I get a Object required error when activating a header in word.
How to set the header as a activated object and insert a picture on the right top side ?

```
Sub insertPicInWordHeader()
        Dim wdApp As Object
        Dim wdDoc As Object
        Dim rng As Range
        'Turn off error handling since if the Application is not found we'll get an error
        'Use Late Binding and the GetObject method to find any open instances of Word
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        wdApp.Visible = True

        On Error GoTo 0

        'Check to see if we found an instance.  If not you can create one if you desire
        If wdApp Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No open files of Word found"
            Set wdApp = Nothing
            Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            wdApp.Visible = True
        End If

        myFile = "c:\users\bsa\Documents\test.docx"
        Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(myFile)
        wdDoc.Activate

        'Check if there are documents in the found instance of Word
        If wdApp.Documents.count > 0 Then



        For Each oSec In wdDoc.Sections
     'This next line gives Error 424 "Object required "
        For Each rng In oSec.Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
            With rng
                .Tables.Add Range:=rng, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=1, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitWindow
                With .Tables(1)
                    .Borders.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
                    .Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
                    .rows.SetLeftIndent LeftIndent:=-37, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
                    .Cell(1, 1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture Filename:="c:\users\bsa\Documents\test.png", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
                End With
            End With
    Next
    Next
        End If

        'Clean up the Object when Finished
        Set wdApp = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: try replacing Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary with the number 1

Comment: For Each rng In oSec.Headers(1).Range gives the same error

Comment: Shouldn't it be For each rng in Osec.Headers(1) ? You are stepping through each range in header not each range in the headers first range

Comment: For Each rng In oSec.Headers(1) without the .range gives : object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Why do you think you need to loop ranges in a Header? There is no `Ranges` collection in a Word `Range` object. In any case, you've declared `rng`as an **Excel** `Range`, not a Word `Range` (you'd need to declare as `Object` since you're using late-binding). Fix that, first, and `Set` to the Header Range (without the `For...Next`) and see how far that takes you...

Comment: Thanks Cindy, I changed the code, indeed I have one header per section..., but then how to insert an external picture from there.. upto With oSec.Headers(1) it is ok now.

Comment: Solved.. updated the code for other users reference

Comment: A reminder for using the site: In order to answer people in comments it's necessary to "ping" them by putting `@` before the screen name, for example: @cindymeister I only looked at this again by chance :-)

Comment: PLEASE to *not* update the code in a question in order to "solve" it. This does NOT help future users - it's confusing. The Question box is for *quesitons*; the Answer box is for *answers*. I'm going to roll back your edit; you can put the corrected code in an Answer. Please include some explanation as to what the problem was and how you solved it. *THAT* will help future users :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @cindymeister I solved it in this manner andd post it for other users

```
Dim shp As Object
 For Each oSec In wdDoc.sections
         With oSec.Headers(1)
          shp = .InlineShapes.AddPicture(myPath & company & ".png")
           'delete other things in header
           .Range.Delete
           .Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture Filename:=myPath & company & ".png", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
           .Range.shp.Height = m_oWord.InchesToPoints(0.72)
           .Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = 2 ' 1 center 2 right
         End With
  Next
```